# How can I find out which namespace an attribute refers to in the current scope?

Tags: javascript, svg, namespaces, scope

Suppose I have an embedded svg:

```
<svg 
  width="5cm" 
  height="6cm"
  viewBox="0 0 5 6"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
...
  <a id="foo">...</a>
...
</svg>
```

I want to add an arbitrary attribute to `#foo` with `.setAttributeNS()`, but only given the attribute name (e.g. `xlink:href`) and value, not the attribute namespace.

Is there a way to look up what namespace a name belongs to? It seems like there should be because I could hard code `<a xlink:href="...">` and it would resolve to the proper namespace, so there should be some scoping I can take advantage of.

For the `xlink:href` example, I could just traverse up the ancestors of `#foo` until I found the `svg`'s `xmlns:xlink` attribute, and use that value for the namespace, but it seems like it should be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the W3 specification: use [`lookupNamespaceURI`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-lookupNamespaceURI).

Answer (score 0):

When using the correct namespaceURI, if the namespace already have a prefix, then the DOM implementation should use it.

```
var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>',
    "application/xml");
doc.documentElement.setAttributeNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
    "href", "data:text/plain,yep");
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));

>>> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:text/plain,yep"/>
```

Other than that, there is indeed no other way than to traversing the nodes somehow and figuring it out yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Would setAttribute work? It doesn't require a namespace.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.setAttribute

Or you can pass null to setAttributeNS.

Comment: setAttribute can only create attributes in the null namespace it's the same as setAttributeNS(null, ...) You can't use it to create xlink:href attributes.